# Can I flash a different stock firmware's build number

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware

Can I flash a boot.img file same model but different build number?

My device: Infinix Smart 5 X657C

Comment: I've tried this on a realme device and it worked. So you may try, at your own risk.

Comment: read boot.img off device with mtkclient

Comment: Hello, I rooted my phone successfully. But my wifi and bluetooth aren't working. Any fix for this?